# Check a number's modulus from every number in a list in a if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program that involves checking if a number's modulus is zero for every number in a list, and then, if it's modulus of all of them is zero, it adds it to the list. Like this:

```
nums = [1,2,3,5]
if( var1% *Everything in nums* ==0):
    nums.append(var1)
```

If you're wondering, It's for calculating primes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function called [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) for this kind of thing.

```
nums = [1,2,3,5]
if all(var1%n==0 for n in nums):
    nums.append(var1)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast answer